# formvalidation validate only if there is file uploaded

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin

Hi I am using this plugin [formvalidation](http://formvalidation.io/) and I am new with this, I have a form with file upload and I want to check if there is a file being uploaded and if there is I will validate this to accept (jpeg,png,gif). and if there is none I will not validate.

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="fname" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pic">Upload here</label>
    <input type="file" id="pic">

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, you are saying you want to check if file selected is jpeg, png or gif. So, what's wrong with below solution? Maybe, I didn't understand you well.

Comment: I mean if there is a file uploaded the validation will enable if there is no file no validation.

Comment: I see I aplogize. I can still submit even there is no file uploaded.

Comment: It's alright. I'm glad, it works for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `data-fv-file-type` option for [FormValidator](http://formvalidation.io/validators/file/).

> The allowed MIME type, separated by a comma.
>   For example: Setting image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf only allows to upload JPEG, PNG image and PDF document.

Use it like `data-fv-file-type="image/jpeg,image/png,application/gif"` to validate file extensions while uploading.

Also, remember to enable the validator by setting `data-fv-file="true"`

**Example**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="avatar"
            data-fv-file="true"
            data-fv-file-extension="jpeg,png"
            data-fv-file-type="image/jpeg,image/png"
            data-fv-file-maxsize="2097152"
            data-fv-file-message="The selected file is not valid" />
```

Comment: can I ask what is "2097152"  is this kb ?

Comment: @jemz It's bytes. You can delete that attribute if you don't need it.